# Select specific array and create and plot a new array in MatLab

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot

I have created random lines and I want to chose some of them in order to plot them in red, while the rest will be plotted in blue.

My code so far is

```
%Initial line values

tracks=input('Give me the number of muon tracks: ');
width=20;
height=5;

Ystart=15.*ones(tracks,1);
Xstart=-80+160.*rand(tracks,1);
Xend=-80+160.*rand(tracks,1);
X=[Xstart';Xend'];
Y=[Ystart';zeros(1,tracks)];
b=(Ystart.*Xend)./(Xend-Xstart);

for i=1:tracks
    if ((Xend(i,1)<width/2 && Xend(i,1)>-width/2)||(b(i,1)<height && b(i,1)>0))
        plot(X(:, i),Y(:, i),'r');%the chosen ones!
        hold all
    else
        plot(X(i),Y(i),'b');%the rest of them
        hold all
    end
end
```

The output is

[image]

One idea would be to create new vectors and try to plot them. My try on that is the following

```
%Initial line values

tracks=input('Give me the number of muon tracks: ');
width=20;
height=5;

Ystart=15.*ones(tracks,1);
Xstart=-80+160.*rand(tracks,1);
Xend=-80+160.*rand(tracks,1);
X=[Xstart';Xend'];
Y=[Ystart';zeros(1,tracks)];
b=(Ystart.*Xend)./(Xend-Xstart);

countHot=0;
countCold=0;

for i=1:tracks
    if ((Xend(i,1)<width/2 && Xend(i,1)>-width/2)||(b(i,1)<height && b(i,1)>0))
        countHot=countHot+1;
   else
        countCold=countCold+1;
   end
end

Xhot=zeros(countHot,1);
Yhot=zeros(countHot,1);
Xcold=zeros(countCold,1);
Ycold=zeros(countCold,1);

for i=1:tracks
    if ((Xend(i,1)<width/2 && Xend(i,1)>-width/2)||(b(i,1)<height && b(i,1)>0))
        Xhotend(i)=Xend(i);
        Xhotstart(i)=Xstart(i);
        Yhotend(i)=Yend(i);
        Yhotstart(i)=Ystart(i);
     else
        Xcoldend (i)=Xend(i);
        Xcoldstart(i)=Xstart(i);
     end
end
```

The thing is that it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas or advice would be more than welcome!

Comment: I think try `plot(X(:, i),Y(:, i),'r');%the chosen ones!` in your first code

Comment: @Dan: Thank you very much for your comment! This alternative you suggested plots only red lines and ignores the logical operations.I'll edit my question, using your plot and adding the output.

Comment: Perhaps I should have changed the other ones. It is working!!! Would you mind posting it as an answer so that I can accept it? What does the code you provided do?

Comment: Yes I meant you should change both lines - answer posted

Comment: I've added a brief explanation in the answer, you should take some time to read through the whole article I've linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first code is almost correct, you just need to plot the columns from `X` and `Y` rather than just simply single points:

```
%Initial line values

tracks=input('Give me the number of muon tracks: ');
width=20;
height=5;

Ystart=15.*ones(tracks,1);
Xstart=-80+160.*rand(tracks,1);
Xend=-80+160.*rand(tracks,1);
X=[Xstart';Xend'];
Y=[Ystart';zeros(1,tracks)];
b=(Ystart.*Xend)./(Xend-Xstart);

for i=1:tracks
    if ((Xend(i,1)<width/2 && Xend(i,1)>-width/2)||(b(i,1)<height && b(i,1)>0))
        plot(X(:, i),Y(:, i),'r');%the chosen ones!
        hold all
    else
        plot(X(:,i),Y(:,i),'b');%the rest of them
        hold all
    end
end
```

`X(i)` will plot a single element from `X`, see [Matlab's linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) to understand why. `X(:, i)` uses [subscript indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85544) with the colon operator `:` meaning all the rows in this case.